# altering datatype from string to integer in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need help changing a column called `streams` (number of times a song/artist was streamed on Spotify) from a string datatype to an integer in BigQuery so I can perform math on it.

When I did autodetect, it picked string, but all the values were numbers as high as 1.5 Billion. Do I cast it as an integer, or do I alter the column?

I believe it chose string because the numbers have commas, so when I perform `MAX()` or `MIN()` it doesn't work properly.

I tried:

```
SELECT
    CAST(streams AS NUMERIC) AS streams
FROM
    table
```

I got this as an error:
`Invalid NUMERIC value: 1,592,909,789`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Strip our the commas then alter or cast.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PARSE_NUMERIC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#parse_numeric) function! See example below

```
SELECT PARSE_NUMERIC('1,592,909,789') AS streams
```

with output

[image]